# ereg to preg_match PHP7

Tags: php, preg-match, php-7

As i switch to PHP7 I have problem (Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function ereg())

My question is how to change from preg_match, because when i change preg_match("[0-9]{1,2}",$head) I get output ........

My code below:

```
    $prevodi = explode('@',$word['prevod']);
    foreach ($zborovi as $zbor)
    {
        $atr = "";
        echo '<div class="words">';
        $tmpprev = $prevodi[$cnt];
        $pred = preg_split("[.]",trim($tmpprev));
        $len = strlen($tmpprev);
        $cut = 0;
        $lng = count($pred);
        if ($lng > 1)
        {
            $cnt1 = 0;
            while ($cnt1 < $lng-1)
            {
                $head = trim($pred[$cnt1]);
                $cut = $cut + strlen($pred[$cnt1]) + 1;
                $cnt1 = $cnt1 + 1;
                if (preg_match("/\d{1,2}/", $head)) continue;
                if (strpos($head,'(') === false || strpos($head,'(е)') !== false) $atr = $atr.$head.'. ';
            }
        }
        echo '<span class="zbor_1">'.$zbor.'<span class="atribute">&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$atr.'</span></span><br />';
```

Comment: Since you switched to PHP 7, it's obvious that `ereg` is deprecated since PHP 5.3.0. `ereg` had no regex delimiters. `preg_match` requires delimiters either `/` or `#` so that would be like `preg_match("/[0-9]{1,2}/", $head)` or `preg_match("#[0-9]{1,2}#", $head)`.

Comment: @Perumal93 this is exactly my answer :) you can just vote it, you know...

Comment: I was already typing it before you answered. As soon as you answered, the post was put on hold to avoid getting any answers futher. Thereby I couldn't post the answer and thought to at least provide it in comment. By the way, I have no objection voting up your answer. Done. :)

Comment: haha :) thanks! got my vote on one of yours too.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
if (preg_match("/\d{1,2}/", $head))
```

Instead.

btw, note that it could also be `preg_match("/[0-9]{1,2}/", $head)`. The only difference is that pattern in `preg_match` should be wrapped in `start` and `end` char (it could be any of `/#+@`)

Comment: I have still bad output, http://prntscr.com/dn8fa2.

Comment: I'm not sure what I suppose to see there

Comment: on PHP 5.4 I get this http://prntscr.com/dn8gok output on PHP 7 I get ...........

Comment: How do you know the problem is with the `ereg`? what is the content of `$head` ?

Comment: Ok i made edit of my post, please see

Comment: Check this: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/283976e84a007680f3e9e8456145e190786811ab (exactly the same result. Don't forget to change the PHP version to 5.X and ignore the deprecation warning).